# Terminology for a type of indecomposable module

Tags: terminology, modules

Let $R$ be a ring. Is there a name for an $R$-module that is indecomposable, and each of its quotients is also indecomposable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for finitely generated modules these are exactly the modules which have a unique maximal submodule.  As such I believe they are called local modules, although I have also heard the term quasi-local modules and am not sure what the distinction is between those two terms.

Comment: Viewing them from a ring-theoretic viewpoint, calling them local modules would be natural. However, I have seen the term local module refer to this situation where $R$ is a local ring. Maybe this could be where quasi-local modules are different?

Comment: Quite possibly.